# Routing between openvpn interfaces/instances

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have 2 openvpn instances on one server (TCP and udp). One has clients in subnet `10.8.0.0/24` and another `10.8.1.0/24`. Server IPs are `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.1.1`:

[image: openvpn server with 2 instances and 2 clients]

Is it possible to ping `10.8.0.2` client from `10.8.1.2` client?

1. I added route to `10.8.0.0/24` on `1.2` client via `10.8.1.1` so ping packets with dst `10.8.0.2` address should go to openvpn server and come from `tun1`  interface.
2. I also enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `sysctl.conf` and rerun `sysctl --system`.
3. Then I configured iptables to forward:

   ```
   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun0 -s 10.8.1.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.8.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   ```

But still it does not work... I am missing something...

---

Also need to add analogical route on other client!

Comment: Does `10.8.0.2` have a route to `10.8.1.0/24` via the server? You will have to add routes both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is that I were needed to add route on both clients

Comment: Leaving it here for others: Also on server, do not forget to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Also check your firewall rules.